# What is the actual base class of all Android classes?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity

Before now, I have read articles and tutorials that say the base class of all Android components is the `Application`. But when I take a deeper dive into the inheritance, I find out that the `Application` class inherits from `ContextWrapper` which equally inherits the `Context` class too.

Funny thing is the `Activity` class also inherits from `ContetxtWrapper`

Why isn't the `Context` class referred to as the base class of all android components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Application class in Android is the base class within an Android
>   app that contains all other components such as activities and
>   services. The Application class, or any subclass of the Application
>   class, is instantiated before any other class when the process for
>   your application/package is created.
>
> This class is primarily used for initialization of global state before
>   the first Activity is displayed. Note that custom Application objects
>   should be used carefully and are often not needed at all

[Reference](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class#:~:targetText=Overview,your%20application%2Fpackage%20is%20created.)

```
 Why isn't the Context class referred to as the base class of all
 android components?
```

> The Application class in Android is the base class within an Android
>   app that contains all other components such as activities and
>   services.

I think above line's will remove your confusion as base class does not only mean's what it implement/extend's it's more about what it contain's.

By your logic if you go deeper into hierarchy at-last all the Classes like Application/Activity/ContextWrapper will be extending `[Object Class][2]`

So Object Class should be base class in Android.

But,

As Documentation say's

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has
>   Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the
>   methods of this class.